# Why can't this json by parsed in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

using qt5 and trying to parse a json

here's the function:

```
void MainWindow::parse(QString &json){

    QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8()));
    QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
    QJsonArray result = obj["results"].toArray();
    QJsonValue location =result.at(0);
    QJsonValue now = result.at(1);
    QJsonValue time = result.at(2);
    cityName = location.toObject().take("name").toString();
    status = now.toObject().take("text").toString();
    qDebug()<<time.toString(); // this qdebug is for testing
}
```

the json Qstring looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "location": {
                "id": "WX4FBXXFKE4F",
                "name": "北京",
                "country": "CN",
                "path": "北京,北京,中国",
                "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai",
                "timezone_offset": "+08:00"
            },
            "now": {
                "text": "晴",
                "code": "0",
                "temperature": "-4"
            },
            "last_update": "2016-12-09T23:25:00+08:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect output from `qDebug` to be `"2016-12-09T23:25:00+08:00"` but it's just `""`

Also `cityname` and `status` turn out to be set to `""`.

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you check `result.size()` ? Have you try to pass and check `QJsonParseError *error` in `QJsonDocument::fromJson` ?

Comment: Step through the code with debugger and examine variable values. If you can't figure it out by that, then add debug prints between each statement, and edit the question with that code, and it's full output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON string, `"results"` is an array of objects, each object has the keys `"location"`, `"now"`, and `"last_update"`. And each of `"location"` and `"now"` is a JSON object with different keys.

You are accessing the result object as if it was an array, you should access it as an object using keys to get values you are looking for:

```
QJsonDocument doc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonByteArray));
QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
QJsonArray results = obj["results"].toArray();
//get the first "result" object from the array
//you should do this in a loop if you are looking for more than one result
QJsonObject firstResult= results.at(0).toObject();
//parse "location" object
QJsonObject location= firstResult["location"].toObject();
QString locationId= location["id"].toString();
QString locationName= location["name"].toString();
QString locationCountry= location["country"].toString();
QString locationPath= location["path"].toString();
QString locationTimeZone= location["timezone"].toString();
QString locationTimeZoneOffset= location["timezone_offset"].toString();
//parse "now" object
QJsonObject now= firstResult["now"].toObject();
QString nowText= now["text"].toString();
QString nowCode= now["code"].toString();
QString nowTemperature= now["temperature"].toString();
//parse "last_update"
QString lastUpdate= firstResult["last_update"].toString();
```